# tabbar background changing color when selected on certain tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I have one tab in a tabbarcontroller that has a navigationcontroller in it and when I select that tab, the tabbar background changes color. How do I change it to not change the tabbar background color when this tab is selected?
[image: Original]

[image: When contacts selected]

Answer (score 1):

It will work try it :)

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

OR

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

I s "Undeter bottom bars" in the navigation controller